# jQuery datepicker changes in date format

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, datepicker

the below code isn't working for me. The date switches from 15/5/2012 to 05/15/2012 whenever I try to change it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date").datepicker({ 
    });
    var myDate = new Date();
    var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var prettyDate = myDate.getDate() + '/' + month + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
    $("#date").val(prettyDate);
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Sounds like a localization problem. What country are you in?

Comment: I'm based in the United Kingdom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please specify the date format as 'dd/m/yyyy' in the datepicker constructor.

```
 var options = {
                dateFormat: "dd/m/yyyy"
            };
            $('#Item').datepicker(options);
```

Comment: How do I go about doing that?